# How to restore Postgres cluster from pg_probackup archive

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-basebackup

I'm trying to configure continuous backup solution using pg_probackup tool. So far I did the following:

1. Configured `archive_command` according to the docs
2. Created backup using `pg_probackup backup` command with a `stream` mode
3. Restored using `pg_probackup restore` on another computer

However, I failed to restore database backup by manually copying files and setting `restore_command` in `recovery.conf`. Here's what I've done:

1. Created new data dir and copied files from `pg_probackup` to that dir
2. Created `recovery.conf` with `restore_command` set to (I'm using Postgres on Windows so paths are Windows-style) `'"<path to pg_probackup.exe>" archive-get -B <backup dir> --instance <instancename> --wal-file-path "%p" --wal-file-name %f'`
3. Started Postgres server

As far as I can see recovery went fine - server is running. However, there're errors in the log file:

```
ERROR:  invalid page in block 0 of relation global/1262
```

and I assume something went wrong with recovery after all.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post pg_probackup version. 1. What exactly went wrong with `pg_probackup restore`. Can you post error message? 2. You manually copied files from `backup_dir`/backups/`instance_name`/BACKUP_ID/database?

Comment: @GrigorySmolkin, I already asked this question here https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_probackup/issues/78 and got an answer (I assume from you)